# How to create Google signup button in android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using jetcompose android with kotlin and i am trying to create a google signup/signin button.
I could only create the SignInButton object. But i didnt find anyway on how to render it.

**val signupButton = SignInButton(LocalContext.current)**

Package from where i imported SigninButton

**com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton**

I am trying to render the signupbutton but unable to render using the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` is a View,  **not a Composable** so it won't be rendered inside of a Composable context. To render Views that are commonly used in XML layouts you should **use AndroidView** into a Composable context and put the View inside it.

```
AndroidView(
            factory = { ctx ->
                SignInButton(ctx).apply {
                    setOnClickListener {
                        //Handle on click
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "On SignInButton clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
```